# Why is Snap and Apparmor not friends?

Tags: 20.10

Ubuntu 20.10
Snap and Apparmor is cluttering up dmesg.

This looks unnecessary:

audit: type=1400 audit(1616045514.211:73): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/gdm/greeter/applications/gnome-initial-setup.desktop" pid=1727 comm="pool-org.gnome." requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0

Any tips to fix all the Apparmor denies Snap messages?